# How to put legend outside the plotting area in Julia pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, legend

I am trying to find a way to put the Julia pyplot backend legend outside of the plotting area. I found some posts discussing this but I can't find a consistent answer. For example I find this post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/location-of-the-legend-in-pyplot/1311

but the problem is that it seems axes() is no longer available in pyplot.

P.S.  User ImportanceOfBeingErnest asked me to put the code. The following code is from post that I put the link to:

```
x = 0:0.1:3*pi
y = sin(x)
z = cos(x)
ax = axes()
plot(x,y,label="sin(x)")
plot(x,z,label="cos(x)")
grid("on")
legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1.05,1],loc=2,borderaxespad=0)
ax[:set_position]([0.06,0.06,0.71,0.91])
```

And the error I get:

```
MethodError: no method matching axes()
Closest candidates are:
  axes(!Matched::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:593
  axes(!Matched::Core.SimpleVector, !Matched::Any) at essentials.jl:594
  axes(!Matched::Base.Generator) at generator.jl:52
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[3]:7
```

Comment: `axes()` is still available in the python version of pyplot, so I would be very very supprised if the julia binding removed it. In any case, show the code you attempted, such that people can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Julia 1.1 you can use this code:

```
using PyPlot

x = 0:0.1:3*pi
y = sin.(x)
z = cos.(x)
ax = plt.axes()
plot(x,y,label="sin(x)")
plot(x,z,label="cos(x)")
grid(true)
legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1.05,1],loc=2,borderaxespad=0)
ax.set_position([0.06,0.06,0.71,0.91])
```